# ClientError HeadObject when collecstatic AWS S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a VPS and I'm trying to collectstatic (Django) using AWS S3.

When I try to `python manage.py collectstatic` I got this error:

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request`

**More context**

I have another VPS with same project and works.
I tested with same aws credentials (user and bucket) and I get the same error.
Testing localy works.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: put this envar `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=sa-east-1`.